# Разные результаты при тестировании программы

Tags: python, рекурсия, дерево

Допустим в клетке Jupyter Notebook имеется минимальный интерфейс с кнопкой к которой привязан обработчик, который вызывает в свою очередь некоторую функцию из другой клетки.

Там же где кнопка имеется поле в которое можно указать путь к файлу с начальными данными (они обрабатываются в функции).

Теперь странности: при использовании первого набора данных выдаются приемлимые результаты, а при перестановке на другие данные и обратно уже другие результаты (хуже чем были).

Никакой random нигде не используется.

В самой функции если уж на то пошло создается что-то по типу мн-ва из дерева решений (само дерево строится рекурсивно).

P.S. При использовании одного дерева решений результаты не меняются...

Comment: Ну, наверное вы используете какую-то глобальную переменную, в которую что-то пишется и это как-то влияет потом на последующие запуски.

Comment: Уже проверял на глобальные. Удалось локализовать ошибку до момента где в цикле создаются объекты деревьев решений причем в случае с худшими результатами начиная со второго дерева их структура начинает повторяться. В случае если не менять данные структура всегда разная.... p.s. каждое дерево просто добавляю в список и далее по сути он сразу используется и уничтожается.

Comment: 1) нет ли у используемых в коде функций дефолтных параметров в виде коллекций? 2) при создании списков и т.п. вы, надеюсь, используете везде новые списки, а не клонируете/очищаете одни и те же?

Comment: хм походу из-за дефолтного [] была ошибка =)

Comment: при создании корня под неиспользуемые признаки был список выделен по умолчанию и далее уже использовался в рекурсии...

Comment: Спасибо вам, а то у меня уже мозг вытек от поиска ошибок...

Comment: Ну, это один из типовых косяков у начинающих питонистов )  Нужно просто запомнить - никаких дефолтных коллекций в параметрах, только дефолтный `None` )